# faulty login system, will not allow logins

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

ok, i got it sorted thanks to LordALMMa, but now i have another problem. I want to determine if the user clicks Admin or User radiobutton when registering. I think i should append it to the end of the line on the text file where the name and password is, but how would i do it? Here is the relevant code:

Radio Button Check

```
public bool radioButtons()
    {
        string usertypebutton;
        if (!userButton.Checked && !adminButton.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select an account type");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (userButton.Checked)
            {
                usertypebutton = "User";
            }
            else
            {
                usertypebutton = "Admin";
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
```

Streamwriter for registering:

```
public void mySW()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Other\myFile.txt";
        string userName = userNameBox.Text;
        string password = passwordBox.Text;
        string usertype = usertypebutton;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Username: {0} Password: {1} Type: {3}" , userName, password, usertype);

            // No need to close nor dispose your StreamWriter.
            // You're inside a using statement for that!
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Thanks for registering! \n\nYou may now log in!", "Registration SuccessFul");
        Application.OpenForms[0].Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Logging In:

```
 private void logonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Loads your users storage
        var users = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt");

        // Creates the line with username + password
        var usernamePassword = String.Format("Username: {0} Password: {1}", userNameBox.Text, passwordBox.Text);

        // Locates the user on your storage
        var userFound = users.SingleOrDefault(_u => _u.Equals(usernamePassword));

        if (userFound != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome back, " + userNameBox.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you have entered incorrect details\n\nPlease try again");
            userNameBox.Text = "";
            passwordBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

So (I think) essentially i want to pass the value usertypebutton from radiobutton method, to the SW. How would i do it, as i'm already passing a boolean value?

Anthony

Comment: I hope this is just for example and you're not really storing login information in a text file.

Comment: Your register page writes "Password:" to the file twice.  That said, please don't actually do this.  Writing passwords as plaintext to a file on disk is a really bad practice, as most users will reuse standard passwords in many places (even though they really shouldn't.)  If you really need to support authentication, take the time to research it and understand it.

Comment: You need to step your code in visual studio. Put a breakpoint on the comparison that fails under NEEDS FIXED! What is user? What is the string you are comparing it to? Why is it different?

Comment: How many users are in your file?  You are only reading the first line in the file and checking against that.  Also, I agree with Shoe about this being an example; or something you are doing to help learn :)

Comment: sorry, yes, i noticed that when i posted it an changed it to username immediately, but it still fails. im gonna assume its because it just reading the first line. So how do i set it to read all the lines, not just the first?

Comment: and this is for a piece of software for my boss, hes not bothered about encryption etc, he just needs somewhere to store names and passwords somewhere, so a text file will suffice for now. i need to learnabout encryption and databases but for now this will do :)

Comment: Piece of advice for using this site. If someone answers your question, mark it as the answer and consider the question closed. Don't overwrite a new question on the old one because it destroys the integrity of the question and the answers already posted.

Comment: okie doke, will post a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony, dispite the fact that storing logins this way is a major security problem (it's not even a risk anymore), there are some changes to your code that I'd do.

The issue is that you're not storing "Username: [username] Password: [password]".
If you double-check your saving method, you're storing "Password: [username] Password: [password]". That's why they are never found.

Here follows some changes:

Consider:

```
public void mySW()
{
    string path = @"C:\Other\myFile.txt";
    string userName = userNameBox.Text;
    string password = passwordBox.Text;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        // This overload makes your life easier by auto-formatting variables for you.
        // Also, avoid the "string1 + string2" concatenation mode.
        // Use String.Format instead. It's easier to read and keep over time.
        writer.WriteLine("Username: {0} Password: {1}", userName, password);

        // No need to close nor dispose your StreamWriter.
        // You're inside a using statement for that!
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Thanks for registering! \n\nYou may now log in!", "Registration SuccessFul");
    Application.OpenForms[0].Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

And your other method should look like:

```
{
    // Loads your users storage
    var users = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt");

    // Creates the line with username + password
    var usernamePassword = String.Format("Username: {0} Password: {1}", userNameBox.Text, passwordBox.Text);

    // Locates the user on your storage
    // This uses Linq syntax with lambda. Linq without lamba looks similar to SQL.
    // Lambda is a bit more advanced but reduces code-size and it's easier to understand (IMHO).
    // This code will iterate through users (list of string) and try to retrieve one that's equal to the contents of usernamePassword.
    var userFound = users.SingleOrDefault(_u => _u.Equals(usernamePassword));

    // If null, indicates that no username/password combination was found.
    if (userFound != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome back, " + userNameBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you have entered incorrect details\n\nPlease try again");
        userNameBox.Text = "";
        passwordBox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

I'm not checking for the exception. SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if 2 or more records are found mathing the search pattern.

I'm not checking that because this will increase complexity here with try-catch and also because for that to work properly, I'd have to check if they exits BEFORE recording, so changing the register method.

But I think you've got the idea here.

Comment: i understand the implications, but its just a local software for my boss, and its not for anything secure, its purely to determine whos using the software, thats all. i understand i need to learn security, but this will suffice for now. what does var userFound = users.SingleOrDefault(_u => _u.Equals(usernamePassword)); mean?

Comment: It's a linq expression to search, within the collection (`users`), for a record that's equal to the variable. If two or more are found, this will throw an exception. If none is found, it will return null (that's why I've checked for null). If one is found, it's retrieved for you already.

Answer (score 2):

One part of the problem is that you are not writing the same string that you're reading:

`writer.WriteLine("Password: " + userName + " " + "Password: " + password);`

I'm guessing that was a typo in your post... but if not that could be your issue.

The other problem is probably this right here:

`using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))`

If you look up the documentation on that overload of the StreamWriter constructor, you'd see that you specified `append = true`.  You are appending each set of login credentials to a file on its own line.  But then later, you are only reading the first line of that file.  So you will always read the first set of credentials that were entered when the file was first created.

That aside, I hope you are just doing this as an experiment since it is not a secure way of managing passwords to write them to a file like that.  Also, you don't need to call Close and Dispose on a Stream if you wrap it in a `using` block, so you should stick to doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your output files? You are writing ***Password***: X Password: Y:

```
writer.WriteLine("Password: " + userName + " " + "Password: " + password);
```

and you are checking ***Username***: X Password: Y

```
if (user == ("Username: "+userNameBox.Text.Trim()+" "+"Password: "+passwordBox.Text.Trim()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding line as

```
writer.WriteLine("Password: " + userName + " " + "Password: " + password);
                  ^1                              ^2
```

`^1` must be `Username:`

There are some points which I cannot pass without pointing:

1. What would you do if file structure corrupted?
2. What if a user wants to register twice with same username and password?
3. Please encode the passwords. This is not ethic. You put at risk your members who uses same account information in somewhere else.
4. Try using a database which is stronger and faster than a text file.